# How to write regexp for finding :smile: in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regular expression, in JavaScript, for finding the string starting and ending with `:`.

For example `"hello :smile: :sleeping:"` from this string I need to find the strings which are starting and ending with the `:` characters. I tried the expression below, but it didn't work:

```
^:.*\:$
```

Comment: Regex101.com will often serve to explain to you why a regular expression isn't working, for example: https://regex101.com/r/NT9qya/1

Comment: Like @DavidThomas said, it looks like the ^ and $ parts of your reg ex are causing you problems. That site explains why.

Comment: Do you want to replace those or do you want to just get them? Anyways `:.*?:` and `:[^:]*:` will do.

Comment: What about `"hello :smile:sleeping:"` or `"hello :smile sleeping:"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you not only want to find the string, but also replace it. For that you should look at using a capture in the regexp combined with a replacement function.

```
const emojiPattern = /:(\w+):/g

function replaceEmojiTags(text) {
    return text.replace(emojiPattern, function (tag, emotion) {
        // The emotion will be the captured word between your tags,
        // so either "sleep" or "sleeping" in your example
        //
        // In this function you would take that emotion and return
        // whatever you want based on the input parameter and the
        // whole tag would be replaced
        //
        // As an example, let's say you had a bunch of GIF images 
        // for the different emotions:
        return '<img src="/img/emoji/' + emotion + '.gif" />'; 
    });
}
```

With that code you could then run your function on any input string and replace the tags to get the HTML for the actual images in them. As in your example:

```
replaceEmojiTags('hello :smile: :sleeping:')
// 'hello <img src="/img/emoji/smile.gif" /> <img src="/img/emoji/sleeping.gif" />'
```

**EDIT:** To support hyphens within the emotion, as in "big-smile", the pattern needs to be changed since it is only looking for word characters. For this there is probably also a restriction such that the hyphen must join two words so that it shouldn't accept "-big-smile" or "big-smile-". For that you need to change the pattern to:

```
const emojiPattern = /:(\w+(-\w+)*):/g
```

That pattern is looking for any word that is then followed by zero or more instances of a hyphen followed by a word. It would match any of the following: "smile", "big-smile", "big-smile-bigger".

Comment: Thanks for the response. This one is working fine for me and now, I need to accept "-" as well how I can  change please help me.:)

Comment: Added my response to the answer

Answer (score 0):

The `^` and `$` are [anchors](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html) (start and end respectively). These cause your regex to explicitly match an entire string which starts with `:` has anything between it and ends with `:`.

If you want to match characters within a string you can remove the anchors.

Your `*` indicates zero or more so you'll be matching `::` as well. It'll be better to change this to `+` which means one or more. In fact if you're just looking for text you may want to use a range `[a-z0-9]` with a case insensitive modifier.

If we put it all together we'll have regex like this `/:([a-z0-9]+):/gmi`

match a string beginning with `:` with any alphanumeric character one or more times ending in `:` with the modifiers `g` globally, `m` multi-line and `i` case insensitive for things like `:FacePalm:`.

Using it in JavaScript we can end up with:

```
var mytext = 'Hello :smile: and jolly :wave:';
var matches = mytext.match(/:([a-z0-9]+):/gmi);
// matches = [':smile:', ':wave:'];
```

You'll have an array with each match found.